# Is it Possible To call a Project With '?' in Its name?

Tags: iphone, xcode

When I try to test my project on the iphone, I get 'a signed resource has been added modified or deleted' message. I changed the project name to not include '?' in it, and then it worked.

Is it allowed to have '?' in the project's name in XCode?

EDIT: Found this link which answered my question: http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/04/17/signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted/

In short it tells you what I expected: You can't put '?' in your project name. See my answer below how to allow '?' in your app name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the solution.

As I've written in the question, I found out about this link:  http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/04/17/signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted/

In short, if you want to have '?' displayed in your app name you need to:

1. Change 'Bundle display name' within xcode's project properties. Tap on the project name -> TARGETS->Info->Bundle display name.
2. Make sure that your project name doesn't contain '?' in it.
3. test the app on the iphone.

Notice that if you were trying to run the app using the simulator, it would allow the project name to allow '?'.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Since Bundle Display Name (what user will see under the icon) is set separately in Info.plist to whatever you like, there's no reason to keep special characters in product name.